# Bounded and "weighted" sum of squares that needs to find another bound - Solved?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, inequality, solution-verification, cauchy-schwarz-inequality

i have a set of equations with inequalities and bounds to consider. I was able to reduce the original problem to the following form:

(1) $\sum_{i=1}^n x_i^2d_i <= 1$

(2) $\sqrt{\sum_{i=1}^n x_i^2} <= M$

So what we want to assume is that all $d_i$ are **positive** and that at most the $x_i^2$ "weighted" by the $d_i$s are summing up to 1. Clarification, the $d_i$s do not have to add up to one etc. despite they are acting like "weights":

$\sum_{i=1}^n d_i>0$

Key is to assume, that the $d_i$ values are kind of given and then regardless of the $x_i$s we want to things work like this:

Then, if the eq. (1) holds, then the eq. (2) should hold too. I.e. if the (1) equals one or less it should be possible to found a bound $M>0$ for the eq. (2), and actually that is what we want to show: if (1) is true, then (2) must be also for some $M<\infty$.

And as a sidenote, the case falls for the bound $M$ once not all $d_i$s are positive. This should happen, and is intuitively true, but what I want to show is that assuming some positive set of $d_i$s and given then that eq. (1) holds then the eq. (2) holds too for all $x_i$s satisfying eq. (1) given the $d_i$s.

Edit:

One possible solution, or at least a foothold. Since $d_i>0$, a square can be taken, let's define:
$s_i^2=d_i$. Then let's put this into eq. (1):
$\sum_{i=1}^n x_i^2d_i = \sum_{i=1}^n x_i^2s_i^2$

Looks familiar to Cauchy-Schawrz inequality, but that does not seem to be enough at least for now.

**Found a solution, please check below and comment!**

Comment: Are you looking for *one* value of $M$ that works for *any* set of numbers $\{x_i\}$? Or is it OK for every sequence $\{x_i\}$ to have a different $M$?

Comment: @JohnBarber "Or is it OK for every sequence {xi}
 to have a different M?" Yes. Please check my answer below that I posted just after your comment.

Answer (score 1):

Got an answer. I considered deleting my question but I will keep it here so someone could verify my approach. Let's forget all the Cauchy-Schawrzs etc.

Let's build case from:

$\sum_{i=1}^n x_i^2d_i\le1$

Let's say $D=\min\{d_1,...,d_n\}$. Then, let's notice that the eq. (2) I gave, could be written as:

$\sqrt{\sum_{i=1}^n x_i^2} \le M \Rightarrow \sum_{i=1}^n x_i^2\le M^2$

Now the eq. (2) feels more managable. By combining some information, we can get:

$D\sum_{i=1}^n x_i^2 \le \sum_{i=1}^n x_i^2d_i \le 1$

From this, we can derive that:

$D\sum_{i=1}^n x_i^2\le 1$

Basic arithmetics:

$D\sum_{i=1}^n x_i^2\le 1 \Rightarrow \sum_{i=1}^n x_i^2\le 1/D$

Take the square root to arrive at the original definition of eq. (2) for LHS:

$\sum_{i=1}^n x_i^2 \le 1/D \Rightarrow \sqrt{\sum_{i=1}^n x_i^2} \le \sqrt{1/D}=1/ \sqrt{D}= 1/ \sqrt{\min\{d_i\}} =M$

Now we got some clearly defined bound that is $M>0$ strtictly, if all $d_i$ are positive, since if the minimum of $d_i$ is negative so will be also $1 / \sqrt{\min\{d_i\}}<0$ and that won't fit for the conditions of $M$.